# Segmentation fault occurred during calculating pi using GMP on Perl

Tags: perl, gmp, pi

I'm trying to calculate pi using GMP on Perl, however my code ended with segmentation fault. As to why it ended with segmentation fault I'd like to know.

I tried to isolate the cause. It appears the segmentation fault occurred when a result of the calculation for pi was output. Concrete code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use GMP::Mpf qw(:all);

my $n = 100000;
my $i = 1000000;
my $cnv = sub{return mpf(shift, $i);};

my $pi = $cnv->(4.0) * ($cnv->(4.0) * arctan($cnv->(1/5)) - arctan($cnv->(1/239)));

print $pi . "\n";

sub arctan{
        my $x = $cnv->(shift);
        my $at = 0;
        $at += (($_-1)%2==0?1:-1)*($cnv->(1.0)/$cnv->(2*$_ - 1))*$x**(2*$_-1) for (1 .. $n);
        return $at;
}
```

Comment: How did you install `GMP::Mpf`? I could not find it on metacpan.

Comment: I installed it from gmp-6.1.2.tar.lz on gmplib.org. After building GMP itself and moving ./demos directry, I installed GMP.pm, GMP/Mpf.pm etc.

Comment: I was able to install `GMP::Mpf` from `gmp-6.1.2.tar.lz`, Ubuntu 18.10, perl 5.29.3. On my system there seems to be a problem with the `arctan` function. For example `say arctan(1.1)` freezes until I press CTRL-C.

Comment: Changing `$n` from 100_000 to 1000 it computes `atan(1.1)` in 1.3 seconds, for `$n = 2000` it takes 3.14 seconds. So it seems it is working only taking a long time to complete

Comment: $n is number of counts for "for" loop in arctan functioin. Does this relate to the segmentation fault ? All right, I confirmed segmentation fault did not occurred after $n was decreased. Thank you.

Comment: Running out of memory or stack? Run it under `gdb`

Comment: I also think there is a possibility that lack of memory happened... This machine has 1024MB RAM...

Comment: where did you get that formula for pi?  note that your 1/5 and 1/239 will be imprecise (unless GMP::Mpf is using some very deep magic indeed) since it it calculated using perl's normal floating point, not GMP.

Comment: I'm using Machin's formula.

Comment: This issue was resolved after "print" was replaced with "GMP::printf" when $pi was output to STDOUT. Thank you everyone.